# How to solve this?

Tags: resistors

how to solve this problem? i wasn't able to make a circuit with VCCS that would be parallel on a 5 ohms resistor and a resistor with some value to subtract 100V. or am i approaching it wrong?
[image: problem image]

i'd like if someone guide me to a page where i can understand how all of this works

edit1: what i had first in mind
[image: what i had first in mind]

edit2: my solution, tho i don't know if it is correct but sounds the most logical. 
[image: my solution]

Comment: You have a non-linear relationship between v and i. Can't solve that with resistors alone.

Comment: solve it however you like. i figured out the vccs should be sensing a voltage across some resistor and then adjust accordingly

Comment: You asked how to solve the problem 29. Right? Reading the question (a), I see no problem in determining a 5 Ohm resistor in parallel with an ideal 20 A current source.

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr: We don't give answers to homework questions but guide the OP through the steps to work it out for yourself. Can you delete this?

Comment: @Transistor: No, I see no reason to delete my comment. In fact it was more a questioning than an answer. When the OP mentioned VCCS (Voltage Controlled Current Source) I wanted to make sure that he was not using problem 29 as a starting point for a practical implementation of the current source, for example using Op Amps. If I were to "solve" the alleged OP's homework I would have posted a step-by-step answer (as I regularly do) and not as comment. So I do not agree with your request.

Comment: i won't deny that this is an assignment. and i can't deny that my instructor is new as an instructor. i don't mind concealing the answer from me but at least guide me through. i rarely solve my assignment so you can consider this as a normal question. so if i can have a hint or an answer that would be great.

Comment: what i had first in mind: 2 resistors and the vccs is parallel to the 5 ohms and 5 ohms in series with a 25 ohm that was calculated as such: 100V+20V; 20=R(4);R2=5; 100=R(4); R1=25

Comment: I think your problem is that you're looking at it using a controlled current source, which is overcomplicating things. It should work fine with a fixed current source, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: i won't be able to achieve the results in the table above. that's why i went with vccs

Comment: how to subtract 100V? i can't hook a 100V battery in the countering the input voltage lol what if a put a 100V rated lamp in series instead of the 25 ohm? that would be a cheap shot but i need something to subtract 100V and how to do it

Answer (score 3):

According to the table your device has an open-circuit voltage of 100V and an internal resistance of 5Ω, which is equivalent to this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faRuii.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But you have this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEgYKo.png)</sup>

So the question is; can you replace a voltage source and series resistor with a current source and parallel resistor, and if so what values are required?

Firstly the device's internal resistance has to be 5Ω. Since a current source has infinite resistance, you can get the required internal resistance by simply making R1  = 5Ω.

Next make the current source 20A. When the terminals are open circuit all this current must pass through the resistor, causing it to drop 100V. Now you have the equivalent of 100V with 5Ω in series!

Finally you want to know the output power when a 20Ω load is applied. Since your device is also equivalent to a voltage with series resistance, you can use that version of it to calculate the current draw and terminal voltage under load.

100V / (5Ω+20Ω) = 4A. 20Ω * 4A = 80V. 4A * 80V = 320W.